# Troubleshoot Azure Authentication

Tags: azure

I am having issues and getting a 401 Unauthorized error on an Azure Function after enabling Authentication. I would like to get more informations, maybe a log or something, but it appears to be happening before the logging of the Azure Function.

Looking at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/cloud-partner-portal-orig/cloud-partner-portal-api-troubleshooting-authentication-errors#unauthorized-error) documentation is really not very helpful. I get a valid token from the AAD, using the credentials from the App Registration, but I don't know where to look for further hints.

Comment: are you trying with Easy Auth? https://www.voitanos.io/blog/securing-an-azure-function-app-with-azure-ad-works-with-with-sharepoint-framework

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio no. With the integrated Azure authentication & authorization feature. I managed to solve it (somehow?), but a way to troubleshoot this would still be a good idea.